# Swift 3 - How to declare an NSOrderedSet to use setVocabularyStrings?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, nsorderedset

I want to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SpecifyingCustomVocabulary.html) function's prototype for adding vocabulary to SiriKit. Apple's documentation shows the following sample code:

```
let workoutNames = self.sortedWorkoutNames()
let vocabulary = INVocabulary.shared()
vocabulary.setVocabularyStrings(workoutNames, of: .workoutActivityName)
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents/invocabulary/1638998-setvocabularystrings), I need to use an `NSOrderedSet` type for `self.sortedWorkoutNames()`.

How to declare it and set it with an array of `Strings`?

**EDIT**: About the context project, I'm using Intents with Siri. The goal here, is to use specific word like 'Benchpress' or 'Chicken' just to start my workout app with an INStartWorkoutIntent already implemented and working like a charm.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset There is a `convenience init(array: [Any])`. So something like that: `let workoutNames = NSOrdered.init(["word1", word2"])`?

Comment: Thanks for your response but It is not working...

Comment: "it is not working" is maddeningly uninformative. When something doesn't work, state the specific error you're getting, or how it fails to meet your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at Apple's sample code for SiriKit, you can tell that their function `sortedWorkoutNames()` returns an `NSOrderedSet`. Look at the type of `workoutNames` in the Objective-C version:

```
NSOrderedSet* workoutNames = [self sortedWorkoutNames];
```

In Swift that would be

```
let workoutNames: NSOrderedSet = self.sortedWorkoutNames()
```

If you have an array that you want to pass to `INVocabulary.setVocabularyStrings(_:of:)`, you'd need to convert it to an ordered set. As @larme said in his comment, NSOrderedSet has an initializer that takes an array as input.

Your code might look like this:

```
let myVocab = ["Benchpress", "Squats", "Deadlift"]
let myVocabSet = NSOrderedSet(array: myVocab) //Convert myVocab to an NSOrderedSet

let vocabulary = INVocabulary.shared()
vocabulary.setVocabularyStrings(myVocabSet, of: .workoutActivityName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I found similar one on GitHub but I've some issue, even using yours, with the 'setVocabularyStrings', Xcode telling me : ' 'setVocabularyStrings(_:of:)' is unavailable: INVocabulary is not available to extensions. The main app is responsible for providing all vocabulary.' Do I miss import or something ? My current import are UIKit and Intents.

Comment: "not available to extensions"? You're trying to write an app extension? You need to provide a more complete description of your problem. Please go back and edit your question to provide more background.

Comment: I'm doing this in Intent. Wait, I will edit my main question.

Comment: Done, sorry for this mess.

Comment: So could you help me please ?

Comment: I haven't used SiriKit before. My information is based on reading the docs. If you're trying to add vocabulary from an app extension then it sounds like you are out of luck.

Comment: Ok, hope I'll find. I will post the answer if I achieve to fix my issue. Thanks for your time and your responses @Duncan C.

Comment: The vocabulary supporting the intent should be added in the base app, not the intent.